# sudo apt-get update error on am335x evm board

Tags: 13.10, arm

I have am335x evm board installed Ubuntu 13.10 from [rcn-ee.net](https://rcn-ee.net/deb/microsd/saucy/bone-ubuntu-13.10-2014-02-16-2gb.img.xz). Now I want to install Ubuntu desktop but I’m getting some errors. I’m getting following console output when I type `sudo apt-get update`

```
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com saucy/main Sources                                  
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
```

I thing there is no problem on my network subsystem because I can ping to `www.google.com.tr` and IP of `91.189.88.140` like below.

```
ubuntu@arm:~$ ping www.google.com.tr                                            
PING www.google.com.tr (173.194.39.120) 56(84) bytes of data.                   
64 bytes from bud02s02-in-f24.1e100.net (173.194.39.120): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 tims
64 bytes from bud02s02-in-f24.1e100.net (173.194.39.120): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 tims
64 bytes from bud02s02-in-f24.1e100.net (173.194.39.120): icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 tims
64 bytes from bud02s02-in-f24.1e100.net (173.194.39.120): icmp_seq=4 ttl=49 tims
^C                                                                              
--- www.google.com.tr ping statistics ---                                       
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms                  
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 58.149/58.412/58.685/0.307 ms
```

Please could you give me any suggestion to solve this issue?
Best regards
Emre

Comment: An error 403 doesn't mean that you weren't able to reach the server; it means that you needed to provide a username and password, but didn't provide one or it was incorrect, which shouldn't happen.

Just to check, are you able to go to ports.ubuntu.com? You should see a directory listing.

Comment: can you ping ports.ubuntu.com ?

Comment: How can I check user name and password, are they my own ubuntu session user name and password or not? I dont have any browser on my ubuntu arm linux so I could not check if Im taking the listing of directories, there is no telnet too. But I can reach ports.ubuntu.com via my pc. Thank you

Comment: yes I can ping ubuntu@arm:/$ ping ports.ubuntu.com
PING ports.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sawo.canonical.com (91.189.88.140): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=56.5 ms
64 bytes from sawo.canonical.com (91.189.88.140): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=56.0 ms
64 bytes from sawo.canonical.com (91.189.88.140): icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=56.4 ms
64 bytes from sawo.canonical.com (91.189.88.140): icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=56.2 ms

Comment: Any advice please..